# How to calculate the sum of the 5th to 10th non-zero values in a row?

Tags: excel

I have a row, like this one:

| 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 7 | *8* | *1* | 0 | *3* | 0 | *1* | 0 | *3* | 0 | *4* | 8 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

How can I calculate the sum of the 5th to 10th non-zero values (8, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4)?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Could there ever be less than 5 non-zero values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who have access to the `FILTER` function you can use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER(A1:R1,A1:R1<>0),{5,6,7,8,9,10}))
```

Comment: @StanShvaika if that worked then why the tag for Excel 2010? it should not work in that edition.  Not that I care you chose this one, but we should probably fix the tag.

Answer (score 3):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:R1,N(IF({1},AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(A1:R1)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:R1))+1)/(A1:R1<>0),{5,6,7,8,9,10})))))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Or this non array version since the `0` between the 5th and the 10th will not affect the SUM:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:R1,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(A1:R1)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:R1))+1)/(A1:R1<>0),5)):INDEX(A1:R1,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(A1:R1)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:R1))+1)/(A1:R1<>0),10)))
```

[image]